# How can I turn ObservableProperty List<string> field into ListBox bindable property? .NET Core 6 WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-core, windows-community-toolkit

I have searched thoroughly but no same question.

I am trying to make work community toolkit Mvvm `ObservableObject ObservableProperty` property with a WPF application.

It turns out that Mvvm  ObservableProperty only works on fields not properties. Also we cant bind WPF elements to fields therefore I can only bind WPF ListBox into a property.

So here my question. How can I turn ObservableProperty field into bindable property and how can I bind it?

I know `ObservableCollection` but I am trying to make work `ObservableProperty`

Here my simple code behind

```
          public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    public cstest myclass = new cstest();

    [INotifyPropertyChanged]
    public partial class cstest
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        public List<string> _lstTest = new List<string>();
    
        public List<string> lstTest { get { return _lstTest; } }
    }
 

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myclass._lstTest.Add(new Random().Next().ToString());

        var gg = myclass.lstTest;
    }
```

I am trying to bind `lstTest` to my ListBox on Main Window

```
 <ListBox Name="lstBox" ItemsSource="{Binding myclass.lstTest}" Margin="290,101,113,122"/>
```

But couldn't figure out yet. Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I expected that user with 21K score understands what duplicate means (hint: it contains the solution). but no: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74214006/how-can-i-turn-observableproperty-list-field-into-listbox-bindable-property-ne. don't blame community toolkit, when you can't make a property: `public cstest myclass = new cstest();` <- it is a field. and don't blame community toolkit when you use List instead of ObservableCollection. ObservableProperty for a property which never changes after initialization - it has zero sense

Comment: @ASh OK you have valid points. So can you give me an example that shows how can you utilize ObservableProperty in a wpf application to demonstrate same affect as ObservableCollection

Comment: "same affect as ObservableCollection" - what makes you think it is possible? they have different purposes. ObservableProperty is just a shortcut for implementation of INPC. in your example INPC isn't even necessary.

Comment: @ASh the naming makes me think. OK so what do I assumed is not possible I suppose?

Comment: @Clemens, I have already tried that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74214006/how-can-i-turn-observableproperty-list-field-into-listbox-bindable-property-ne. and after converting field to property, list has to be converted to OC, or added items won't be visible

Comment: @ASh I saw that, still the problem is here.

Comment: And of course `lstTest` must be declared as ObservableCollection. ObservableProperty (besides incorrectly used) won't do anything useful here. It would not notify about collection changes. The question does not make much sense.

Comment: @Clemens yes I know ObservableCollection. But I am trying to do same without using it if possible.

Comment: Not possible when you only add items to an existing collection. Create your own collection type that implements INotifyCollectionChanged when you don't want to use ObservableCollection.

Comment: @Clemens I just made an ObservableProperty updating label content. However still working on List for ListBox

Comment: @Clemens ok i think i understand the logic now. ObservableProperty works only on non collection types right?

Comment: @ASh ok i think i understand the logic now. ObservableProperty works only on non collection types right?

Comment: That is a misconception. ObservableProperty is a helper to implement INotifyPropertyChanged - for any type of property. ObservableCollection implements INotifyCollectionChanged. When you add items to an existing collection object that is held by a property, this does not change the property, so firing the PropertyChanged event of INotifyPropertyChanged has no effect. You need to fire the CollectionChanged event of INotifyCollectionChanged, which ObservableProperty does not do.

Comment: @Clemens are there equivalent of INotifyCollectionChanged  in community tools like ObservableProperty  ?